# What does it mean that a web hosting server 'support python'?

Tags: python, django, cpanel, web-hosting

I‘m learning django recently days. And today I plan to learn how to put it on my server.
My web hosting server supplier tell me that my server support python. I searched online, someone said that to deploy django, you'd better have lighttpd installed on your server.

How to see if I have that lighttpd on my server?
If there isn't, how can I deploy django on my server? I use cpanel to manage it.

Finally, what does a web hosting server `'support python'` mean?

Comment: Why would you go by some random posting that says you need to install lightppd? Why not look at the official documentation on deploying, which says no such thing?

Answer (score 2):

At first you should take a look at ['How to install Django'](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/) at the official page. As we read:

> If you want to use Django on a production site, use Apache with
>   mod_wsgi. mod_wsgi can operate in one of two modes: an embedded mode
>   and a daemon mode. In embedded mode, mod_wsgi is similar to mod_perl –
>   it **embeds Python within Apache and loads Python code into memory** when
>   the server starts.

So python support is necessary to execute any python script on the server side. You probably have been told to use `lighttpd` only for development purposes. As the doc above says, it's better to use apache which is most possibly installed at your hosting service provider's server.

The instruction linked above will tell you how to install Django. Nevertheless I'd suggest installing web server locally at you computer if you just want to learn.

Comment: My web hosting is using Apache, but I can only access it with cpanel, can I deploy Django with Cpanel?

Comment: Worth a try, just follow the steps in installation guide. As I mentioned before, for educational purposes it's suggested to work on local machine.